# JAVA - error: incompatible types: double[] cannot be converted to double

Tags: java

Estoy tratando de corregir errores sobre un código, pero hay alguno que no sé por qué está fallando.

Las funciones creadas son las siguientes:

- Asignar el valor de PI

```
    public static final double PI = 3.141592653589793;
```

- Calcular el volumen de un cilindro

```
    public static double volume(double r, int h) {
        return PI + (r*r) * h;              
    }
```

- Descomponer en unidades, decenas y centenas el valor del volumen obtenido

```
    public static double [] decompose(double number) {
        int units, tens, hundreds;          

        units = (int) number%10;
        number = number/10;
        tens =  (int) number%10;            
        number = number/10;
        hundreds = (int) number%10;         

        return new double [] {units,tens,hundreds};
    }
```

Finalmente tengo el método main:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {                

        double radio = 4;                              
        int height = 8;
        double volume = 0;

        volume = volume(radio, height);                    
        volume = decompose(volume);             //<-- ERROR en esta línea           

        this.units = units;
        this.tens = tens;
        this.hundreds = hundreds;

        System.out.printf("Volume %.2f \n", volume);        

        System.out.println("Units: " + units);
        System.out.println("Tens: " + tens);
        System.out.println("Hundreds: " + hundreds);
    }
```

El error mostrado está en `volume = decompose(volume)` 
Cómo puedo solucionarlo? Por qué ocurre el error?

*NOTA: soy consciente que hay más errores por solucionar, pero mi objetivo es entender el error por el que pregunto en esta cuestión ahora.*

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que estás devolviendo un array de double en el método decompose() y la variable volumen la tienes declarada como double.

Si haces algo así:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    double radio = 4;
    int height = 8;
    double volume = 0;
    double[] volumeArray;

    volume = volume(radio, height);
    volumeArray = decompose(volume);

    this.units = volumeArray[0];
    this.tens = volumeArray[1];
    this.hundreds = volumeArray[2];

    System.out.printf("Volume %.2f \n", volume);

    System.out.println("Units: " + units);
    System.out.println("Tens: " + tens);
    System.out.println("Hundreds: " + hundreds);
}
```

Debería arreglarse el problema.

Comment: muchas gracias. He ejecutado pero me da error. Entiendo lo que querías decir. Publicaré el error en otra consulta.

Comment: ¿Qué error te da?

Comment: el error es ```java: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context``` en la línea ``` this.units = volumeArray[0];```

Comment: Vale, seguramente es porque las variables: units, tens y hundreds no las tienes declaradas como static, y al usar el this. dentro del método public static void main (String[] args) que si que es estático. Deberías revisar que si debería ser estático y que no.

Comment: Camara, he hecho una definición global de las variables en vez de usar el 'this'